# Canvas items not rendering properly

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

I have defined the two functions to render a circle and a triangle.  Very straight forward stuff.

```
function circle(offset, size){
  var color = $("#color option:selected").val();
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  radius = size * 1;

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(offset, 2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
 }

 function triangle(offset, size){
  var color = $("#color option:selected").val();
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var width = size * 6;
  var height = size * 5;
  var padding = 0;

  // Draw a path
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(offset + width/2, padding);
  context.lineTo(offset + width, height + padding);
  context.lineTo(offset, height + padding);
  context.closePath();

  // Fill the path
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
}
```

I am have added the canvas to my page with:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

For some reason I can see the circle and square a not rendering correctly.  See attached screen shots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can almost guarantee that it is because you are setting the width and height of the Canvas using CSS width and height and not the `<canvas>` html attributes.

You need to define the width/height either in the canvas tag:`<canvas width="500" height="500">`

or in code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
```

And not by CSS. If you did this:

`<canvas style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">`

Then you would have a 300x150 canvas (the default size) that was scaled/warped to be 500x500, which is almost certainly what you're getting.

(I wrote the above freehand so there might be a typo, but you get the idea)

Comment: Yup.  I changed it to: <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400" style="padding:1em;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid #000;margin-top:1em;background:#ddd;"></canvas> and it works perfectly!  Thanks!